# Does this continuous function admit a projection on this set?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, projection

Let $V:=(\mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R}),\Vert .\Vert)$ the vector space of the continuous functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with the norm $\Vert . \Vert$ which satisfies for all $f \in V : \Vert f \Vert = \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}+ \Vert f \Vert_1$.

Let $X:=\{f \in V : f(0)=0\}\subset V$ and consider the continuous function $\mathbb{1}: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto 1.$

We want to know after determining $d(\mathbb{1},X)$, if the continuous function $\mathbb{1}$ admits a projection on $X$.

Notice that $V$ is in fact a Banach space (equivalence of norms). And also that $X$ is a non-empty convex and closed set of $V$ (kernel of a linear form). Moreover, we know that the theorem of projection concerning prehilbert spaces cannot be applied here.

I meet difficulties to find $d(\mathbb{1},X)=\displaystyle \inf_{f \in X}\Vert \mathbb{1}-f\Vert$.

Let $f \in X$, for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\vert \mathbb{1}(x) - f(x)\vert = \vert 1-f(x)\vert\le 1 + M$, hence $\Vert\mathbb{1} - f\Vert_{\infty}\le 1+M$ and $\Vert\mathbb{1} - f\Vert_1= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\vert 1-f(t) \vert \mathrm{d}t\le 1+M$ where $M$ is the maximum of $f$. Then $\Vert\mathbb{1} - f\Vert\le 2(1+M).$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi. Sorry, how do you define $ d( \mathbb{1}, X )$?? If it is $ d(\mathbb{1}, X ) = \inf_{ f \in X} \| \mathbb{1} - f\| $ then why is it not equal to $1$. Cant you just take a sequence $f_n$ continuous functions which are between $0$ and $1$ and equal to $1$ on $(1/n, 1]$ and $f_n(0) = 0$. Then $f_n \in X$ and $\|f_n - \mathbb{1}\| \to 1$. Moreover, you know $d(\mathbb{1}, X) \geq 1$ by the definition of your norm.

Comment: If not then I apologise.

Comment: $d(1,X)=1$ is correct. @rank_nullity

Comment: For the projection: Notice that $X$ is the kernel of the functional $e_0 \colon C(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ given by $e_0(f) =f(0)$. Notice that $||e_0||=1$ and that $e_0$ does not attain its norm, that is, there is no $f \in C(0,1)$ with norm one such that $|e_0(f)|=1$ (Why?). Moreover, observe that $d(1,X) = |e_0(1)|=1$. Arguing by contradiction, suppose that there exists $g \in X$ such that $d(1,X) = ||1-g||$. It then follows that $||1-g|| = |e_0(1)| = |e_0(1-g)|$ since $g(0)=0$. This leads to $e_0 ( \tfrac{1-g}{||1-g||})=1$ which is impossible.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Thank you but I guess you wanted to write $\Vert e_0(f) \Vert$ no ?

Comment: @rank_nullity Yes it is the definition you wrote but I do not understand well your reasoning ? The sequence of continuous functions you considered does not necessarily take its values on $[0,1]$. Also $\Vert. \Vert$ is a sum of two norms

Comment: @Maman well $e_0(f)$ is a real number, so taking the $C(0,1)$ norm does not make sense.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. I found that $\Vert e_0 \Vert = 2 \vert f(0) \vert$.